# Classification model for recommender system?

Tags: classification, random-forest, recommender-system

I have some data for various customers choosing one of 'n' products or no product. I have some useful features for each customer. I can build a multi-class classification problem out of this data and use a classification model (say, random forest) to learn the data. 
This model will then output one of the following categories:

[0, 1, 2, ..., n]

where 1, 2, ..., n is the 1st, 2nd etc. products, and 0 is when the customer chose not to buy anything.

I want to make this model as a recommender system, i.e., when a new customer (along with all other features) comes along, I know which one of the n products he will more likely buy.

The question is this: in the above setting, I don't know what I should do when the models outputs '0' for the new customer. What should be my action when such a situation, i.e., the new customer is not likely buy any of the products? Or should I formulate the classification problem in some other way? Is there any way we shouldn't formulate the problem as a classification problem at all?

Comment: Think it as this way. In multi-class classification, there are probabilities for each class when predicted. when your prediction is '0', choose next class with highest probability.

Comment: @Not_Dave, thanks. What if the probability of '0' is significantly higher than the probabilities of 1 to n? Is there any other recommender system which could be helpful in such a problem?

Comment: if probability is higher for '0' then choose the class with next highest probability. Say **0** has prob -> 0.7, **1** ->, **2** ->0.05 and so on, then choose '1' in this case. Based on the result from the recommendation, you can retrain your model.